# Loading error LibGDX/Scene2d

Tags: java, json, libgdx, scene2d

I am getting this:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file:
>   ui/skin.json

I am trying to load a skin for my scene2D ui, completely failing at it.

Anyway, when I go to the class, that error gets thrown within the load method, so it's a loading problem right?

Also, why is it not loading?

```
@Override
public void show() {

    // Creates our atlas from our png file containing all the sprites
    atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/atlas.atlas");

    // Create a stage, everything goes on the stage
    stage = new Stage();
    // A skin for the stage
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/skin.json"), atlas);
```

The file is there, named exactly, project cleaned, refreshed and re-imported. Even tried moving it to just the assets folder. Just keeps tossing an error.

This is my json file:

```
{

    "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color": {
        "white": { "r": 1, "g": 1, "b": 1, "a": 1 },
        "black": { "r": 0, "g": 0, "b": 0, "a": 1 },
        "red": { "r": 1, "g": 0, "b": 0, "a": 1 },
        "green": { "r": 0, "g": 1, "b": 0, "a": 1 },
        "blue": { "r": 0, "g": 0, "b": 1, "a": 1 }
    },

    "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": {
        "fontSFNightly": { "file": "fonts/fontSFNightly.fnt" }
    },

    "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
        "heading": { "font": "fontSFNightly", "fontColor": "white" }
    },

    "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle": {
        "mainMenu": { "up": "button.up", "down": "button.down", "pressedOffsetX": 1, "pressedOffsetY": -1 }

    }

}
```

Fairly straight forward, following dermetfans videos so I can learn more about program structure and what not, this is starting to get on my nerves tho lol

Comment: Its probably something in the JSON parsing.  Trying reading/loading the file directly with a JsonReader, or try simplifying the file to see if you can eliminate the parse error and narrow down the problem.

Comment: I managed to fix it after 2 hours of sitting staring at the stack trace....helps if I read down rather than taking the first line as the actual error. I shall leave an answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it.

It turns out there was some sort of issue reading the font object from the JSON file, I was using a third-party font from 1001fonts.com, I am not sure why it would not load.

I changed it to a standard windows ariel font and I am now trying to figure out why the custom font was not working.

Therefore this problem is technically fixed.